# offset google map DirectionsService polyline

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have two polylines drawn on a google maps api v3 directions service.

My problem is that where they overlap on part of the map, one covers the others. I wish to draw 6 lines in total which are bus routes in my city. All routes come back to the same area of the city but it will be very difficult to distinguish them apart.

Is there a way to slightly offset each line?

```
function busRoute2(source,destination){
        // show route between the points
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
        {
            suppressMarkers: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            polylineOptions: { strokeColor: '#000000', strokeOpacity: 0.5 } 
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var request = {
            origin:source, 
            destination:destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the working code (very basic) [polyLine offset map animated](http://beachincalifornia.com/pt/testlines.php) Note: The icon 'offset' property is the percent offset of the icon along the line. 
You need to manipulate the relative 'path' Coordinates (SVG format) of the icon (in your case a line) itself in order to offset it away from the line

Answer (score 0):

Forget my suggestions. I tried to create a repeat icon (2 pixel dot) repeated every 4 pixels offset from the polyLine.  It looks absolutely disgusting and lags the browser.

I am going to have to create a function that edits the coords of the polyline at load time according to angle dLat, dLng and zoom scale.

As you want your markers (stops, buses) and lines to be on one side of the road going one direction and the opposite going back. You also dont want to obscure the road name on the map

If anyone wants to help with this email me at huntington@beachincalifornia.com